# Anime where a kid goes to find a magic city with a magic academy

Tags: story-identification, anime, magic

The anime I'm trying to think of starts with a kid who I believe lost his parents. He's trained on some sort of hot air balloon house and when he finally leaves, he goes to find the magic city with the magic academy, so he can learn.

The first season is him trying to get into the magic city when he finally does, it turns out that the magic city is academy. The headmaster's like a cat or a dog or something. Eventually, the magic city goes to war with the government of that land and they all drive around in airships.

If anyone can help me with the name of this anime, I would be very appreciative.

Comment: Hi, welcome to the site. In roughly which year did you watch this and when do you think it might've been made?

Answer (score 1):

It's called [*Radiant*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Radiant_(manfra)), a French comic book series written and illustrated by Tony Valente. Was looking it up myself.

[image: Front cover of Radiant]

> In the world of “El Pharenos”, a race of powerful monsters called Nemeses fall from the sky. This race infects every living thing they touch. Any humans who survive their contact become cursed, but also gain the ability to wield the magic power known as "Fantasia", thus becoming Sorcerers. Some Sorcerers use their powers for their own gain while others choose to become heroes and protect normal humans from the Nemeses. But whether good or evil, all Sorcerers are mostly treated with fear and contempt by the common folk. There is also an organization known as the Inquisition, which is dedicated to the eradication of Sorcerers.
>
> The series follows Seth, a seventeen-year-old boy who has survived a Nemesis attack. He dreams of defeating all of the Nemeses and bringing peace between Sorcerers and the rest of humanity. To do so, he has to find the place where the Nemeses come from, the legendary Radiant, and destroy it. He and other sorcerers travel the region in search of Radiant whilst avoiding the Inquisition.

Comment: Hi, welcome to SF&F.  Can you add a bit of description about the anime, maybe a link to a site like IMDb, so that it's possible to judge how good a match it is to the question?